# Export Dissected Pcap file to text file using command line

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I am quite new to wireshark. Gone through the wireshark manual for the command line options but still cannot find the right flag or command lines to export the dissected pcap file to text file using command line options.

So in the Wireshark GUI, we have this export dissected packet option, refer image here:
[wireshark gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzJ1X.png)

Does this can be translated fully using command lines for wireshark/tshark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution.

```
tshark -Y icmp -V -r "Filename" > fileoutput
```